# Convert local datetime to datetime with DST

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, dst

How can I convert a local CET datetime ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") column in a dataframe to a CET datetime with DST?

Comment: Any particular language? As it says in [the description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dataframe/info) dataframe is a data structure used by several different languages...

Comment: @HereticMonkey , sorry. I forgot to mention it. The language I am using is Python

Comment: Are any of these datetimes going to occur during the hour of the year where the hour is repeated?  You'll need a way of differentiating those.

Comment: have a look at the [Series.localize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) method - is that what you need?